# jQuery .on event binding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a jQuery JavaScript working with blocks (2, `.delegate`) and (3, `.ready`+`.click`) below for detecting whenever the user clicks a given checkbox. However, if I use the block (1, `.on`, as recommended for jQuery > 1.7) it seems that the event is not bound to the given function:

```
// Block #1: .on
$("#userCheck").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function(){
    alert("hello");
});

/* Blocks are commented since I would like to use .on jQuery function 
// Block #2: .delegate
$(document).delegate('#userCheck', 'click', function(){
    alert("hello");
});

// Block #3: .ready + .click
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#userCheck" ).click(function(){ alert("hello"); });
});
*/
```

The HTML code is the following (only relevant part, generated with Django):

```
{% for r in requests_list %}    
    <tr>
        <td class='rr-e'>{{ r.username }}</td>
        <td class='rr-e'>{{ r.organization }} ({{ r.country }})</td>
        <td class='rr-e-select'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='userCheck' userid="{{ r.pk }}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        
    <tr><td class='row-separator' colspan='3'/></tr>
        
{% endfor %}
```

I am using Firefox with the debugging console from the web developer tools and, in accordance with those tools, everything seems to be ok but nothing happens.

In addition to this, the previous code is working in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/9r6kf/124/

Comment: can you share your markup? also whether the checkbox is created dynamically

Comment: also make sure the id of the element `checkUser` is unique

Comment: `#userCheck` or `#checkUser`? You are not using the same element in the first block.

Comment: Try click event instead if mouseup

Comment: if `checkUser` not in page when code runs need to use delegation syntax for `on()` see docs...similar to delegate but switch event and selector

Comment: After your last edit is obvious you are repeating the same ID ...ID's are uniqe by definition

Comment: Yes, but in the case that I am working with, there is a single item in the list, so there is only a single and unique checkbox with a single and unique id.

Comment: ok..is code wrapped in `ready` handler? `$(function(){/* code*/})`

Comment: I did not wrapped the first block with the ready handler, I only did that for the .click() event function. Now it is working.

Comment: if there is only one element then it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YzRbQ/1/

Comment: Note: since you are using a loop to create the elements it will be advisable to use class attribute to group elements instead of id as ID should be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlietfl said, the key was to wrap the .on() function with the .ready() function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userCheck").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

In addition to this, but not as a solution to this problem, the id for the checkboxes must be changed for it to be unique for all the checkboxes. However, this was not the root of the problem since there was only a single element in the list and, therefore, Django generated only a single checkbox.

However, in the example at http://jsfiddle.net/9r6kf/124/, it works without the need of wrapping that function with the .ready() one. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same id for more than one element as they are meant to be unique identifiers. In this case, the event is being added only to the first occurrence of your ID.

You could use the `class` attribute instead and select your element using `.userCheck`.

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' class='userCheck' userid="{{ r.pk }}"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.userCheck').on('click keyup ...', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Also, it is a best practice to delegate your events to the container element instead of adding them to each element as you are using a loop. The `on` method allows you to do that. Take this example:

```
$('#your-table').on('click keyup ...', '.userCheck', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Related example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RuPzY/1/